# Drawing on top of image in PyQt5 tracing the mouse

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm new to PyQt5. I'm trying to draw on top of a loaded image lines that are tracing my mouse, i.e. pressing the mouse will result in drawing whatever your mouse moves to, while the mouse is still pressed, and stops when we release the mouse.

I saw [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42769995/7252805) and it was very helpful, but I'm trying to do something a bit more complicated.

I think I'm messing up with the events.

What I wrote (which doesn't work):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen


class Menu(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.drawing = False
        self.lastPoint = QPoint()
        self.image = QPixmap("picture.png")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 300)
        self.resize(self.image.width(), self.image.height())
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.image)
        pen = QPen(Qt.red, 3)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = True
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton and self.drawing:
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 3, Qt.SolidLine))
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainMenu = Menu()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use `drawLine` in `mouseMoveEvent`. When you move your mouse, it will invoke `mouseMoveEvent` which will draw a line from the last position, and then it will invoke by itself the `paintEvent`.

Try this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen


class Menu(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.drawing = False
        self.lastPoint = QPoint()
        self.image = QPixmap("picture.png")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 300)
        self.resize(self.image.width(), self.image.height())
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.image)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = True
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton and self.drawing:
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 3, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainMenu = Menu()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]